# Cross Platform Xamarin Navigation Page inside Tabbed Page

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have added Tabbbed Page with navigation Page. e,g

Code Inside tabbed Page.

```
var NavPage = new NavigationPage(new Page1());
NavPage.Icon = "Icon1";
NavPage.Title = "Tab1";
Children.Add(NavPage);
```

above code not showing Page1 on tab1 click.

Could you please tell Is anything wrong with  above code?

Page1 is Content Page.

It work when code like below.

```
 var Page1 = new ContentPage
 {
    Content = button,
 };
 NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(Page1 , false);
 var navigationPage = new NavigationPage(page) { Title = "click" }
```

I want to follow approach one.

Comment: You have set the icon to an upcoming unhandled exception.

Comment: I am new to this,  parden me ..Why It will throw exception ? Is it wrong to have icon to navigation page?

Comment: If you set the resource name to a unexciting name like " " it will throw an exception.

Comment: anyone have solution for this?